# Scrapy is not listening to deny rules

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

For some reason scrapy is parsing data from URLs in my denied rules:
I'm getting parsed data from urls containing /browse/, /search/, /ip/.
I'm not sure where this is going wrong.

Please advise, thanks! Please find my code below:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from wallspider.items import Website


class mydomainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "tp"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain.com",]

    """/tp/ page type to crawl"""

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/tp/', ),
        deny=(
            'browse/',
            'browse-ng.do?',
            'search-ng.do?',
            'facet=',
            'ip/',
            'page/'
            'search/',
            '/[1-9]$',
            '(bti=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?',
            '(sort_by=)[a-zA-Z]',
            '(sort_by=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?',
            '(ic=32_)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?',
            '(ic=60_)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?',
            '(search_sort=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', )
            ,)
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//html')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['title'] = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
            item['description'] = site.select('//meta[@name="Description"]/@content').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

a part of my console log, its grabing /ip/ pages?:

```
2013-12-11 11:21:43-0800 [tp] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/ip/1104329> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/tp/john-duigan)
2013-12-11 11:21:43-0800 [tp] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.mydomain.com/ip/1104329>
    {'description': [u'Shop Low Prices on: Molly (Widescreen) : Movies'],
     'referer': 'http://www.mydomain.com/tp/john-duigan',
     'title': [u'Molly (Widescreen): Movies : mydomain.com '],
     'url': 'http://www.mydomain.com/ip/1104329'}
2013-12-11 11:21:43-0800 [tp] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.mydomain.com/ip/17371019> from <GET http://www.mydomain.com/tp/jon-furmanski>
2013-12-11 11:21:43-0800 [tp] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.mydomain.com/ip/17371019> from <GET http://www.mydomain.com/tp/taylor-byrd>
2013-12-11 11:21:43-0800 [tp] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.mydomain.com/ip/17371019> from <GET http://www.mydomain.com/tp/greg-byers>
2013-12-11 11:21:43-0800 [tp] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.mydomain.com/ip/17371019> from <GET http://www.mydomain.com/tp/tom-bowker>
2013-12-11 11:21:43-0800 [tp] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/ip/21152221> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/tp/peter-levin)
2013-12-11 11:21:43-0800 [tp] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.mydomain.com/ip/21152221>
    {'description': [u'Shop Low Prices on: Marva Collins Story (1981) : Video on Demand by VUDU'],
     'referer': 'http://www.mydomain.com/tp/peter-levin',
     'title': [u'Marva Collins Story (1981): Video on Demand by VUDU : mydomain.com '],
     'url': 'http://www.mydomain.com/ip/21152221'}
```

Comment: It seems there's nothing wrong with your code. Print the `response.url` in the `parse_items` method and verify if the denied urls to be fetched.

Comment: could you post your console log while running the spider? (replace the domain if you want)

Comment: @pault. The console log is quite long, but i hope what's provided is sufficient?

Comment: @pault. if you need to see more let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, the pages were redirecting to a page type that was in my deny rule.  Thank you for all your help!  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

The rules of your `SgmlLinkExtractor` apply when extracting links from pages. And in your case, some of your `.../tp/...` requests are being redirected to `.../ip/...` pages.

```
Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.mydomain.com/ip/17371019> from <GET http://www.mydomain.com/tp/tom-bowker>
```

`allow` and `deny` patterns do no apply to URLs after redirections.

You could disable following redirections altogether by setting [REDIRECT_ENABLED](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#redirect-enabled) to `False` (see [RedirectMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect))

Comment: awesome thanks!  i think i'll turn the redirecting off.